# Exporting from one library if web, another library if native in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I am trying to use Victory Charts (https://formidable.com/open-source/victory) and would prefer to not just use a webview, as they've got a native implementation.

However, I am trying to use the library with React Native Web, and it does not work at all, I get the following error:

```
/Users/myname/Desktop/Projects/myproject/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/victory-native/lib/components/victory-axis.js 10:22
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:22)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| export default class extends VictoryAxis {
>   static defaultProps = Object.assign({}, VictoryAxis.defaultProps, {
|     axisComponent: <LineSegment/>,
|     axisLabelComponent: <VictoryLabel/>,
```

My guess is that I'll need to use two "wrapper" files, Victory.js and Victory.web.js for importing.

Here is my Victory.web.js file so far:

```
Victory = require('victory');

export default Victory;
```

This does not work.

I have also tried:

```
import { VictoryPie } from 'victory';

export VictoryPie;
```

Which gives me the error:

```
/Users/myname/Desktop/Projects/myproject/Frontend/Expo/src/components/utility/Victory.web.js
SyntaxError: /Users/myname/Desktop/Projects/myproject/Frontend/Expo/src/components/utility/Victory.web.js: Unexpected token (3:17)

  1 | import { VictoryPie } from 'victory';
  2 | 
> 3 | export VictoryPie;
```

I just want to be able to use this library on both React Native and React Native Web without it throwing errors. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but this way worked for me:

```
export const VictoryPie = require('victory').VictoryPie;
```